# How Play read messages files

Tags: playframework-2.0

Kindly explain how Play read messages files.I want to understand how play looks for messages files and how it read.
It will be highly grateful if I can see the method and class where it is implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can browse Playframework's source on GitHub.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala

I think that is the file you are interested in. Hopefully you are familiar with Scala, the Java API just ends up calling these Scala classes.

Comment: I have gone through the Message.scala and I notice loadMessages method in DefaultMessagesPlugin class.As per my requirement , I am thinking of calling loadMessages method from Application.java class and pass the path of only one message file, so that Play application read only one message file and create single map out of that.As I am not at all aware of scala programming ,kindly suggest If I am thinking in right way or not.

Comment: @user3454281 I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I suppose that would work as long as the file you're trying to load is in the app's classpath. Also note that you're going to get back a Scala Map object. You can use it or I'm sure there's a way to convert it, but I've never done that.